# Generating families of lambda functions

Tags: python

I would like to generate a family of lambda functions similar to this simplified example:

```
fns = [(lambda x: x == y) for y in range(10)]
```

The result I get from this is indeed a list of 10 functions.  However, all 10 seem to have y bound to 9, which is the last value of the sequence.  For example

```
[fns[i](9) for i in range(10)] --> [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
fns[0](0) --> False
```

Why doesn't this work, and what's a clean work-around?

I've tried this in Python 2.7 and 3.3.

Comment: Change the lambda definition to `(lambda x, y = y: x == y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited due to comment.

```
>>> fns = [(lambda x,y = y: x == y) for y in range(10)]
>>> map(lambda x: x(1), fns)
[False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: What if I had another for loop? Nest the lambda one more time?

Comment: Nope, the one lambda is all the closure you need. Example included in edit.

Comment: We don't another lambda at all. Check my comment in the question.